# Order for ForEach on View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, viewmodel, partial-views

In MVC 2 I have a user control - Partial page as below.

Model has four records

```
id Dtext Dtext1  
1 A, A1  
2 B  B1  
3 C  C1  
4 D  D1
```

On My machine - Output is as above in the ID Order which is expected.

But after deployment output is totally bizarre something like below.

```
D  D1  
B  B1  
A, A1  
C  C1
```

Would like to know how data is sent or retrieved from ViewModel? Why not in the specific Order. Any idea.

I have downloaded MVC source code for investigation but don’t have any clue where to start?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl< MyData>" %>
<% if (Model != null)
   {
%>

    <% 
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {%>
    <%: item.DisplayText %>
        <%: item.DisplayText1 %>
    <% }%>
<%} %>
```

Comment: Are you using the same database for dev and deployment?

Comment: Database server in not same. Sql server configuration is same.  sql script and insert scripts are same. Data in tables is pupolated with scripts on both the databases.  this should not create above issue..!?

Comment: Since no one mentioned it, no sorting in query = unpredidctable row order. Database 101, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing list I assume inside your `MyData` anyways...Use [OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) on your query that fetched the records.In your case say wherever you get yout list of `records`-

```
var result=records.OrderBy(i=>i.id).ToList();
```

Comment: i know how to resolve this problem but i want to know why on one machine data is displayed in ascending order but on other machine Not?  Why not in the specific Order on every machine. Any idea

Comment: using IEnumerable Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable < MyData>>" %>

Comment: It is the way you would fetch records from database...nothing to do on the `view` side of it..I am not sure what exactly may cause it..